# How can directory avoid cloning in Git?

Tags: git, github, git-clone, ogre

`imgui` directory is not empty in Github: https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre/tree/master/Components/Overlay/src

Simultaneously, if I clone with

```
git clone https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre.git
```

I get it empty. Why and how to fix?

Comment: Sorry, read updated version of the question

Comment: `imgui @ 688cf86` means that it's [a submodule](https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre/blob/master/.gitmodules) pointing to commit [688cf86](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/commit/688cf86) of the repository at https://github.com/ocornut/imgui